# Build a WordPress one page scroll theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a wordpress one page scroll theme.

I can not understand how to enable the bootstrap navbar scroll spy (in the static version it works), and I do not understand the file hierarchy.
Do you have any advice?

And if I wanted to give the opportunity to add sections to the home page how can I do it?

Thank you all!

Comment: Don't ask multiple question in a singe thread. You can read the docs for more information. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: sorry. you are right

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself***a before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress: One-page scroll JQuery script not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648470/wordpress-one-page-scroll-jquery-script-not-working)