# WordPress One Page scroll website - how to?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I need some help to understand how to create WordPress One Page Scroll website. I did a standard website before (the one that change content after clicking on menu link), but I can't figure out how to use WP on web page with scroll to section instead of standard sub-sites.

Let me show You structure of my site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
css/bootstrap
css/main.css
etc.
</head>

<body>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
       //This navbar overlaps header and it's fixed to top//
       //Has links to sections (e.g. #one, #two etc.)//
   </nav>

   <header class="masthead">
       //This is also my "front page" displayed on page load with height: 
         100%, width: 100%//
   </header>

   <section id="one" class="bg-primary">
       //first section to scroll to//
   </section>

   <section id="two" class="bg-primary">
       //second section to scroll to//
   </section>
       //first section to scroll to//
   <section id="three" class="bg-primary">
       //third section to scroll to//
   </section>

   <footer id="main-footer" class="bg-primary">
       //Some info about author, website, and social media links//
   </footer>

   js/jquery.min.js
   js/bootstrap.min.js
   js/script.js //my custom scripts
</body>
```

My problem is- how to organize this content for CMS to change every section content via dashboard? 
1. Should I create different page.php for each section (e.g. page-one.php etc) and use:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('page-offer'); ?>

<?php get_template_part('page-tech'); ?>

<?php get_template_part('page-portfolio'); ?>

<?php get_template_part('page-contact'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```

on index.php

2. Or should I create section-one.php, section-two.php etc. and display it on "front-page.php"?

   My second question is- is it possible to create different PHP file with Navbar code, and use this navbars html, and css as WordPress dashboard menu? Or should I create menu in dashboard first (every section is a single page) and then style it with custom css?

And last: How to use custom fields to edit every single paragraph, button content, link etc. via dashboard and allow it to work with POLYLANG to change content language?

Thanks for any help, and apologize for long thread. I'm realy struggling with this.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but if you're trying to scroll to a specific part of the page you can do `scrollTo(xPos, yPos)` in JavaScript

Comment: No, it's not a problem. My JQuery code handles it quite fine. My problem is how to manage this website structure in wordpress using custom fields and multi language content.

Comment: Use the front-page.php file to build single page template

Comment: @RaajNadar so you say, that I should place whole my HTML code to front-page.php?

Comment: Yes it will be display when the website is loaded

Comment: @RaajNadar ok, what about changing content of the website? Should I change it via POSTS or other solution?

Comment: You need to understand wordpress query for loops through posts and display them.

Comment: @RaajNadar Ok so i have multiple posts on my whole website, and I need to change links content (<a>), buttons content, and paragraph content. Displaying posts by ID is not possible, becouse when i want to add a translation to single post it's creating new ID. When i want to get post ID instead of typing it straight every post existing is displayed everywere (one link - multiple post, tones of content, one button- same). 

So, posts aren't the best idea in my case...

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to achieve can you add more details in you question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress: One-page scroll JQuery script not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648470/wordpress-one-page-scroll-jquery-script-not-working)